# Setting grid items to not Overlap when sharing the same row and column

Tags: angularjs, css, flexbox, css-grid

Right now, when two grid items share the same row and column they overlap each over.

```
<div class="some-grid-container">
    <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1">Item 1</div>
    <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

How do I them not overlap? Probably behave like flex items when sharing the same row and column. (Without making an outer container).

Comment: Can you explain why you want to put to Items to one grid element? I do not see any use case for this. Maybe theres a different way with CSS grid to achieve what you want to do.

The actual questions answer is "no, you can not put the in the same place without outer container and without overlapping".

CSS grid is made to exactly place a container to fill the specific area.

Comment: I'm actually using Angular and doing a for loop where rows and columns in a grid container will be the same. I would not be able to use an outer container in this certain loop.I guess they really would overlap if I make them the same row and column and if I don't use a wrapper eh. Welp. 

But, thank you so much for answering.

Comment: Do you want to have these items concatted in one field? If you tell us the target behaviour we might help you. You want several items (texts ?!) to be in one field? If yes, you want to have them in separate containers each? Why don't you just post the whole for loop from angular and ask for that? :)

Comment: @jdickel:  A use case would be having an x-axis of 5 columns (Mon - Fri) and in the y-axis you have times (9AM-5PM).  You have two classes on Monday: (1) Swimming @ Monday 9AM - 11AM. (2) Karate @ Monday at 9AM - 11AM.  Right now if you place both classes in the Monday column they will not be aware of each other and overlap.

What he is wanting are for the positioned grid items to be content-aware and not overlap when set in the same position.  I don't think grid is smart enough to do that unfortunately.  If subgrid was widely supported I think we would be able to accomplish this with ease.

Comment: I get your description but that's not related to the grid. HTML nor CSS is content related since they're both just markup and design languages. They can't be content aware of anything. To design something like this you'll want to have some class management written in JS or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not correct.
Inline styles are not using those braces "{", "}".
And additionally you need to specify the "Item 2" in the second column. If you use the same row and same column then both divs are in the same place for sure.

Try...

CSS:

```
.some-grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="some-grid-container">
    <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 1;">Item 1</div>
    <div style="grid-row: 1; grid-column: 2;">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

This should create a 100% width grid with 2 equally sized columns.

Comment: I was asking if there was some way for the items to not overlap even when when using similar grid-row and grid-column. Changing the column to some other number is not one of my options.

I've also changed my question so that it does not use {}.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? @jlawcordova

Comment: And, did you get the items to push each other out of the way?

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the items in a container.

Example:

```css
.some-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px;
}

.some-grid-container>div {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.some-grid-container>div>div {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-grid-container">
  <div>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```