# Distribute elements of unequal height in two columns

Tags: css, css-grid

*This is a development of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799209/arrange-elements-in-columns-vertically-shifted-relative-to-one-another/53809889#53809889) with a crucial difference: elements to be distributed in two columns are of unequal heights. Please do not treat it as a duplicate.*

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:**

Given an unknown number of elements of roughly similar, but not identical height, the following should be achieved:

**On desktop layout:**

- elements need to be distributed in two columns in the following manner:

  1   2

  3   4

  5   6

  etc
- top element in the right column should be offset from the top border of the container at a greater distance than the top element of the left column, which should produce something like this:

[image]

- distances between the elements in the same column should be the same

**On mobile layout:**

- elements should remain in one column, positioned one below the other in their original order (1, 2, 3, 4, etc)

**PROBLEM:**

- If I try to solve this by assigning `display: inline-block` to the elements, the browser will try to put each pair on a separate line; and every difference in their height will result in unequal spacing between the elements of the same column. Example:

```js
function fillGrid() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const times = [...new Array(10)];
  times.forEach((garbage, index) => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerText = index + 1
    element.classList.add('grid-element');
    container.appendChild(element);
  });
}

fillGrid()
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background: papayawhip;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .grid-element {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
}

.grid-element {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.grid-element:nth-child(even) {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

/* Just to add some disorder to grid element heights */

.grid-element:nth-child(6) {
  height: 150px;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(7) {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

- if I use CSS grid, the browser will create implicit rows for every new pair of elements, and the result will be visually similar to the previous attempt:

```js
function fillGrid() {
  const container = document.querySelector('.container');
  const times = [...new Array(10)];
  times.forEach((garbage, index) => {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerText = index + 1
    element.classList.add('grid-element');
    container.appendChild(element);
  });
}

fillGrid()
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-column: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  background: papayawhip;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .grid-element {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .grid-element:nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
}

.grid-element {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(odd) {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
.grid-element:nth-child(even) {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

/* Just to add some disorder to grid element heights */

.grid-element:nth-child(3) {
  height: 150px;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(6) {
  height: 150px;
}

.grid-element:nth-child(7) {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

- when I specify that I want all elements to go in the same row of CSS grid, they are positioned on top of one another (as discussed, without any solution, in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49974503/setting-grid-items-to-not-overlap-when-sharing-the-same-row-and-column))

This problem is, of course, trivially solved by placing the elements into two separate containers and then positioning these two containers relative to one another. The drawback with this approach is that in mobile layout, these containers will get stacked on top of one another, and the order of the elements will change (instead of `1 2 3 4 5 6` it will be, say, `1 3 5 2 4 6`. I could, of course, draw two layouts on the same page and hide one of them depending on whether this is a desktop or a mobile screen, but I would rather not do so.

Is there a clean CSS-based solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you use Grid properties without `display: grid;`?!!

Comment: Two questions. You mention unequal spacing between the elements as a problem. So, you want the elements to have an equal margin between each one vertically, no matter what the size of the element itself, right? And is it ok for the CSS to specify the size of each element individually?

Comment: I tried to achieve this with Grid. It solves the issue with desktop / mobile view by simply adding `grid-template-column: 1fr 1fr` and changing that to `grid-template-column: 1fr` for small screens. I can't get it to work when the divs have different sizes, though. And even when the divs are all the same size, the bottom/top margins have to be equal on both sides. This is what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/9kgv87fo/

Comment: Something like this ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jsbox6yg/)), or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @BobRodes The effect I am after should be as if the elements in the left column were in their own container, and the elements in the right column were in their own container, and within a container they were just stacked on top of each other with an equal spacing between each other. Only I am trying to do all this without wrapping the elements in additional containers. Don't know if that explanation makes much sense :-)

As for whether it is ok to specify the size of each element placed in the columns, no, I do not know what the precise height of each individual element will be.

Comment: @DavidThomas visually it looks precisely what I am after; but let me take a closer look.

Comment: @DavidThomas after a closer inspection: I am seeing that the grid is changing heights of non-green elements to fit the available slots. Sadly, this is not the effect I am after — what I want is for elements in each column to stack on top of each other completely independently of what elements in the other column are doing. Perhaps a good analogy would be that all odd elements should ideally end up in column 1 row 1, and all even elements should end up in column 2 row 1. Then there will be no implicit extra rows. Only when I attempted to do that, the elements started to overlap each other.

Comment: I'm not asking for the precise height. In grid, if the elements aren't the same size, you specify each element in terms of how many rows and columns it fills. So, do you know the relative heights of the individual elements ahead of time, or will that vary?

Comment: They may vary. Not dramatically, but they will likely not be the same among different items.

Comment: I'll try again. As I understand your requirements so far, you want two columns of elements. The width of each column is the same, so the width of each element is the same. You want to specify the height of each element independently of the others. You want them to be positioned (1) evenly apart, and (2) such that all elements are placed in sorted order, with all odd elements in the left column and all even ones in the right column. Finally, on a smaller screen, you want all elements to stack up in one column, and in sorted order. Is all that correct so far?

Comment: @BobRodes Yep, this is correct. As for the height of each element, it's not that I am specifying it (I only did it to illustrate the problem). Each element will have some content (an image, a paragraph of text, etc.) whose height is unknown, but it's safe to bet that it will be different across different elements.

Comment: Ok, now we're getting somewhere. You want the height to adjust automatically to contain whatever content you have in the elements. I'm glad you declassified that bit of information, since without it, you've been leading everyone down the garden path, even if unintentionally. :) Now, will this content always be text, or will there be images sometimes as well, or what?

Comment: @BobRodes each item is supposed to be condensed info about a podcast episode. So the contents of an item will consist of a title block (of unknown height), an image (of known height), an episode description (of unknown height) and an html5 audio element (of known height). I apologize if that information was in any way relevant, but I thought it could be safely hand-waved away by simply considering "items of unequal height".

Comment: The fact that the content determines the unequal height, rather than you, is significant when you think about the fact that the implementations of each would have to differ. Now, are you going to need to plug in different element content each time you bring up the page, or is the content static?

Comment: Both :-) I was intending to use a static-site generator; so the output files will have static content. However, every time a new content item is added, the page will be re-built, and a new content item will appear on the page.

Our previous implementation of that page was built dynamically at every request, and we used request headers to decide whether to render a mobile or a desktop version (and then there was additional js run on window resize, which could trigger re-rendering of the layout from desktop to mobile or vice versa). But my hope was to find a purely CSS-based implementation.

Comment: CSS grid will calculate the size it needs to fit the largest element in a row and then size all the elements in that row the same. It will not stagger the sizes so that there is the same amount of margin space for each of them. Which you have demonstrated in your example. You can't stack different elements in the same row of the grid; that sort of defeats the purpose of the grid. The grid matrices aren't so much containers as positioning elements. Now, if you want to create two containers, one for each column, they won't stack properly, as you have also seen. (more)

Comment: So, your solutions appear to be to work with margins to position your elements after you know their heights, in which case inline-block is probably simpler than grid and will probably require JavaScript, or to implement your "trivial" solution. Perhaps that solution seems inelegant to you, but the elegant solution that is less than obvious is not, in my experience, to be preferred over the prosaic one that is obvious to anyone. People who have to change your code after you're long gone appreciate well-crafted code, but they appreciate easy to understand well-crafted code even more.

Comment: Ouch! So what you suggesting is to measure the heights of each item, then to manually adjust the position of each item using the inline-block approach; then after another podcast episode is added, to go through the styles again and to manually re-adjust positions of the elements again? This sounds dreadful. Better admit defeat and distribute the elements in two containers using javascript; and add a javascript media query listener (via matchMedia) that will put the items in the single common container for mobile-size screens.

Comment: Or set it all up two different ways ahead of time (one for regular and one for mobile), and use media queries in CSS to show and hide. No JavaScript required. You could also use masonry as Maya Davis has pointed out. For an example of a site that uses it, have a look at www.zergnet.com. Masonry apparently uses absolute positioning to get the effect. (I don't know much about it, but the zergnet site appears to do what you want.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an elegant solution to this problem using only CSS. You're probably better off using a well-tested JavaScript library like [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/) to get this to work. It'll handle the responsive case you mentioned well, since the items will all be in a single container.

Here's a demo with a similar layout to the one you're describing: https://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index.html